# SSRS Report deployment on Report Server in a Sub folder

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

Is it possible to deploy report on SSRS server in a folder structure?
I have a folder structure on my server like:

**Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/Folder 4**

I want to deploy my reports in Folder 4 but when I put the same in the target folder path it pop up a Report Server Login window asking for a user id and password and the same never works where as if I deploy the report on http:\hostname\reportserver , it goes well and the report gets deployed.

The path that I am using for deployment is :

**http://Myhost.com/reportserver/Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/Folder 4**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the spaces in the folder names and check that the same security has been applied through the folder structure.

You''ll need to check that whatever data credentials are also stored in whatever reports are in Folder4. Sometimes moving reports between folders removes the dataset credentials. (also Save As into a new location can remove them as well)

Comment: Removed spaces from the folder name, checked folder permission but the deploy still did not go. It is still asking me for the user id and password.

Comment: Is it the report asking for the credentials?

Comment: Not exactly. Credentials are required only for the Data Source(Hana) which is taken as a Shared Data source.This DS credentials is provided at the time of creating report and never after that. The deployment goes fine on http:\hostname\reportserver but does not work when I add folders to the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot JonTout. I figured out the mistake that I was doing. It works fine now

Comment: what was your fix? Leave the answer here and it might help somebody else out.

Comment: Update the path(Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/Folder 4) in the
Target Dataset,Target Data Source and Target Report Folder and Target Server URL as http://myhost.com/reportserver